# How to add Variable path in MANIFEST file

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I want to a add a path to my MANIFEST file, but this path is machine-dependent: one machine, the path may be

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib
```

but it may be different on another machine.

Is there some syntax for generalizing this path, so it can be recognized by the JVM? Something like `%JRE_HOME%\lib`, perhaps?

Comment: improve grammar and formatting